# Avoiding local dependencies for MSBuild Community Tasks within Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

I'm trying to start taking advantage of the `MSBuild Community Tasks` so right after installing the `.msi` package I've imported `MSBuild.Community.targets` within the `<Project>` element this way:

```
<Import Project="lib\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets" />
```

Interestingly I've noticed such file have a reference to the local installation path in `MSBuildExtensionsPath` and given that in lieu of keeping code dependencies as clean as possible I'm willing to pay the overhead of distributing/versioning them with every project, I was wondering if is it possible to sort of override the default/installation location with a project-relative one in the `.cproj` file?

The actual layout would be like:

```
Dotnet.Samples.Foobar
\src
     Foobar.cs
\lib
     MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets
     MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll
```

Any guidance will be sincerely appreciated. Thanks much in advace for any suggestion you might want to share.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets** specified the path to the dll.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath Condition="'$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
  <MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll</MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can override the path in the project.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>lib</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>      
</PropertyGroup>
```

And leave import the same:

```
<Import Project="lib\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets" />
```